# What actually happenes in this code?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor

In the following code is `Num2(int x)` constructing an instance of `Num1` and destroying it immediately? `Num1(x)` initializes `int a` and `int b` which are private so the derived class can't access them. But, why isn't compiler complaining?

Also, the size of `Num1` is 8, `Num2` is 12 and `Num3` 4.

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Num1 {
        int a;
        int b;
    public:
        Num1(int x) : a(x), b(0) {}
        ~Num1() {}
    };

    class Num2 : public Num1 {
        int c;
    public:
        Num2(int x) : Num1(x) {}
        ~Num2() {}
    };

    class Num3 {
        int d;
    public:
        Num3() {}
        ~Num3() {}
    };

    int main() {
        cout << "sizeof(Num1) = " << sizeof(Num1) << endl;
        cout << "sizeof(Num3) = " << sizeof(Num3) << endl;
        cout << "sizeof(Num2) = " << sizeof(Num2) << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Why is the size of `Num2` 12 when it can't access `a`and `b`? What's the point of that?

Comment: Please reread the chapter on constructors in your book, or throw the book away and get a better one.

Comment: The thing with the `:` is called an initializer list.

Comment: In particular, you should read about initializer lists, and base classes.

Comment: I know about initializer lists and base classes. I don't understand why does the compiler occupy memory for private members when it can't accss them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private variables are there to help with the work behind the scenes in a class, work that the creator doesn't want you interfering in. Just because you can't see or access the private variables, it doesn't mean the compiler's just going to throw them away. Perhaps it will make more sense to you in this example:

```
class Animal {
    int legs;
public:
    Animal(int legs) : legs(legs) {}
    ~Animal() {}
    std::string how_fast() {
        if(legs > 4) {
            return "Super fast!";
        } else if (legs > 2) {
            return "Pretty fast.";
        } else {
            return "Slow.";
        }
    }
};

class Lion: public Animal{
    int humans_eaten;
public:
    Lion(int eaten) : Animal(4), humans_eaten(eaten) {}
    ~Lion() {}
};
```

Here `legs` is private in the `Animal` class because this should already be known to the children. If I am doing calculations in `Lion` that require me to use the number of legs, it will always be 4, however, this is not always the case for `Animal`.

Even though Lion can never access Animal's `legs`, Animal needs to know that number for its calculations in `how_fast`. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Num1 is the parent class of Num2. When the integer x is passed to the Num2 constructor, the base constructor is called passing that argument to it (initializing int a).

Also

```
cout << "sizeof(Num2) = " << sizeof(Num3) << endl;
```

That should probably be

```
cout << "sizeof(Num2) = " << sizeof(Num2) << endl;
```

Comment: Why does the compiler occupy memory it can not access?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? In this case, Num2 directly inherits every private member of Num1, except it cannot access those members. By default, those members are private because you didn't make them public or protected. And if they were protected, you could access them as if a Num2 were a Num1.
<br />
EDIT:
The reason we do this is [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)).

Comment: And here is a _[link](http://pastebin.com/d6maVgPU)_ to a cool example that shows you the natural flow of events that occur from construction to deconstruction. Code is fun. :]